# The client config takes only one end point in wcf 4.0?

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest, soap

I used two endpoints one for soap and one for rest. I needed the soap end point added as a default end point. I tried changing the framework to 4.0. Only the soap end point got added in the client it solved the problem but is there any problems tat would arise?

Answer (score 0):

SOAP and REST are two different architectural styles

WSDL is a SOAP construct and has no knowledge of REST style endpoints. Your client is consuming the WSDL and will therefore only get to see the SOAP endpoint

In WCF endpoints are independent of eachother and so there shouldn't be any issues

Comment: Thats right but i dont want the client to specify the name of endpoint in the constructor .

Comment: Assuming they only have one endpoint defined on the client side they won't need to pass it into the constructor of the WCF proxy

Comment: So this works only with the framework 4.0 right? because in framework 3.5 it takes both the end points into the client